# How can I create events through python on apple's icloud calendar

Tags: python-3.x, icloud

So I've been looking through a few API wrappers for python, like pyicloud found here:

https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud

And apple Icloud intigration, found here:
https://pypi.org/project/apple-calendar-integration/

I want to, ultimately, be able to list, add, edit and delete events, preferably in one API.

Is there such a thing, and if so, where can I obtain it?
Thank you